# Удалить из ссылки все символы кроме цифр?

Tags: php

Есть произвольное поле для телефона. Пользователь вводит в поле телефон с разными символами. Нужно сделать, чтобы все символы очищались, кроме цифр

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?phone=<?php the_field("phone"); ?>"></a>
```

Comment: Используйте регулярные выражения

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov я совсем не разбираюсь, можете показать как будет на примере выглядеть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?phone=<?php print filter_var(get_field("phone"),FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); ?>"></a>
```

Comment: все символы убирает кроме +. Можно его как-то убрать?

Comment: тогда регуляркой ``<a href="whatsapp://send?phone=<?php print preg_replace("#[^0-9]#",'',get_field("phone")); ?>"></a>
``

Comment: Сууупер! Огромнейшее вам спасибо)))))

Answer (score 2):

```
 function cleanPhone($phone){
     return preg_replace("/\D/", "", $phone);
 }
```

Comment: так?
<?php the_field("phone"); function the_field($phone){ return preg_replace("/\D/", "", $phone);}
?>

Comment: так не работает

Comment: `<?= cleanPhone(the_field('phone')) ?>`

Comment: ошибка syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)